# Array fetching all data in the last loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have written code to fetch data of podcast according to categories and get the JSON data, the code seems to work properly but, in the last loop it is giving me data of whole categories instead of the last category id.

```
$podList = $category->getCategoryPodcast();

$output = array();

$json = array();

if ($podList) {

    foreach ($podList as $items) {

        $id = $items->id;

        $episode = $podcast->getPodcastByCategoryId($id);

        $count = count($episode);

        if (!empty($episode)) {

            foreach ($episode as $episodes) {

                    $cat_id = $episodes->category;

                    $output['category_id'] = $cat_id;

                    $output['no. of episode'] = $count;

                    $output['podcast'][] = $episodes;

            } 

        } $json[] = $output;

    } 

}
echo json_encode($json);

die;
```

I expect to have podcast data of the specific category not the data of whole categories combined together in the last loop.

I am getting the following output.

```
[
  {
    "category_id": "2",
    "no. of episode": 2,
    "podcast": [
      {
        "id": "6",
        "title": "Advanced Javascript course",
        "description": "s.kfjhsdlufdgf o",
        "duration": "0:05:05",
        "audio": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-2019011511270942.mp3",
        "image": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190115112709469.jpg",
        "category": "2",
        "added_date": "माघ १, २०७५",
        "category_title": "उमेर",
        "author": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "How to display array inside array?",
        "description": "",
        "duration": "",
        "audio": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-20190114111541297.mp3",
        "image": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190114102432145.jpg",
        "category": "2",
        "added_date": "पौष ३०, २०७५",
        "category_title": "उमेर",
        "author": "John Doe"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category_id": "1",
    "no. of episode": 1,
    "podcast": [
      {
        "id": "6",
        "title": "Advanced Javascript course",
        "description": "s.kfjhsdlufdgf o",
        "duration": "0:05:05",
        "audio": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-2019011511270942.mp3",
        "image": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190115112709469.jpg",
        "category": "2",
        "added_date": "माघ १, २०७५",
        "category_title": "उमेर",
        "author": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "How to display array inside array?",
        "description": "",
        "duration": "",
        "audio": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-20190114111541297.mp3",
        "image": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190114102432145.jpg",
        "category": "2",
        "added_date": "पौष ३०, २०७५",
        "category_title": "उमेर",
        "author": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "How to get pretty URLs",
        "description": "",
        "duration": "",
        "audio": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-20190114111937115.mp3",
        "image": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190114104302103.jpg",
        "category": "1",
        "added_date": "पौष ३०, २०७५",
        "category_title": "गृह पृष्ठ",
        "author": "John Doe"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but I expect to get only one array as the in category_id : 1 the no. of episodes is 1.

```
[
  {
    "category_id": "2",
    "no. of episode": 2,
    "podcast": [
      {
        "id": "6",
        "title": "Advanced Javascript course",
        "description": "s.kfjhsdlufdgf o",
        "duration": "0:05:05",
        "audio": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-2019011511270942.mp3",
        "image": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190115112709469.jpg",
        "category": "2",
        "added_date": "माघ १, २०७५",
        "category_title": "उमेर",
        "author": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "How to display array inside array?",
        "description": "",
        "duration": "",
        "audio": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-20190114111541297.mp3",
        "image": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190114102432145.jpg",
        "category": "2",
        "added_date": "पौष ३०, २०७५",
        "category_title": "उमेर",
        "author": "John Doe"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category_id": "1",
    "no. of episode": 1,
    "podcast": [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "How to get pretty URLs",
        "description": "",
        "duration": "",
        "audio": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podAudio/PodAudio-20190114111937115.mp3",
        "image": "http://shikshak.web/uploads/podImage/PodImage-20190114104302103.jpg",
        "category": "1",
        "added_date": "पौष ३०, २०७५",
        "category_title": "गृह पृष्ठ",
        "author": "John Doe"
      }      
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add a sample json output you are getting and the one you are expecting to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the whole categories combined together because your `output` array is defined out of the loop and it will be filled during each loop iteration.
To fill it with only single category create it inside the loop, so at the next iteration it will be empty array ready to be filled with new data

```
$podList = $category->getCategoryPodcast();

// $output = array();

$json = array();

if ($podList) {

    foreach ($podList as $items) {

        $output = array(); // Create output array here, to fill it with data.

        $id = $items->id;

        $episode = $podcast->getPodcastByCategoryId($id);

        $count = count($episode);

        if (!empty($episode)) {

            foreach ($episode as $episodes) {

                    $cat_id = $episodes->category;

                    $output['category_id'] = $cat_id;

                    $output['no. of episode'] = $count;

                    $output['podcast'][] = $episodes;

            } 

        } 

        $json[] = $output; // fill the $json array with outputs.

    } 

}

echo json_encode($json);
```

the $json output will be something like this

```
[
    [0] => [
        ['category_id'] => 1
        ...
    ],
    [1] => [...]
]
```

Comment: Thank you @line88 for your help but I also had filled the $json array with $output but it didn't give the result where was my actual error?

Comment: @Alisha hey, can you create a [php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), sample. Save and share the link here so it will be easy for me get what are you willing to do. Just fill it with dummy array data.